# I need some basic help setting up CNAME and apache correctly

Tags: dns, apache-http-server, domain, subdomain, cname

I have the grasp of setting up multiple name-based domains on Apache 2 using virtual hosts. Say I have a domain name called 'domain.com'. I now want to set up a sub domain of this, like 'demo.domain.com' and want this to go to a different folder on Apache to serve up a different website.

How would I set this up exactly? Do I need to set up a CNAME and then a virtual host in Apache? Or do I just setup a ServerAlias in Apache? I'm a little confused.

I'm using Slicehost for my hosting and DNS, if that helps. Using Ubuntu Hardy with Apache 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DNS and the server configuration are two different things. For the DNS you will either need a CNAME or an A record for your new subdomain so that it will resolve to the correct IP. The difference is that CNAMEs resolve to other hostnames while A records resolve to IPs.  For example:

```
subdomain.example.com CNAME -> example.com

subdomain.example.com A -> 1.2.3.4
```

Once the DNS is configured correctly you will then need to configure an Apache virtual host for the new subdomain.  Check the documentation here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't too clear on the differences between CNAME and A records. Also, I still thought it wasn't working, but all I had to do was wait for it to propagate. Have a good day Dave.